# @FXML Objects are null in initialize Method

Tags: javafx-8

i have a (shortened) java FX Class:

```
public class MyReportController extends
    javafx.application.Application implements Initializable {

@FXML
private CustomTextField autoTextField;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {


    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(autoTextField, ServiceLocator
            .getInstance().getMeasurementService()
            .getAllMeasurementNumbers());
}......
```

the initialzie method is called, but the autoTextField(and all other FXML components) is null.

The Application is started from another class with the main method.
First i had the main Method in the controller class with the result, that the controller class was instantiated twice.
I think my current problem is related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the same `fx:id` declarations in your FXML as property names to inject. So for example, in FXML, CustomField controll declaration should have `fx:id=autoTextField`. This way dependencies will be injnected upon initialization.

Second thing, please dont use controller class that extends `Application`. This has simply no purpose here. Start application from different class that controller, and the controller class instance will be automaticly created once by `FXMLLoader`