# @FXML controller components are null after initialize

Tags: java-8

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634591/javafx-fxml-is-null-outside-initialize), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320276/fxml-objects-are-null-in-initialize-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910611/javafx-controller-is-always-null) but sadly there is not a single one that resolves my problem. The components are always null. The ids are the same but I still don't know what I am doing wrong. Below is my code :

Application Class.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(LocalFileUtils.getResourceAsURL("RootView.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

RootView.fxml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.MainViewController">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane id="mainAnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Controller Class

```
    package main;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class MainViewController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainAnchorPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Started");
        System.out.println(location); // Prints out he URL of the RootView
        System.out.println(resources); //Always Null
        System.out.println(mainAnchorPane); //Always Null
    }

}
```

The App runs okay. Have I missed something?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jfxtras... This is just regular JavaFX

Comment: Sorry @tbeernot I have removed it. Couldnt find jfx tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FXML you need to define ids different.  the id in FXML must be like this

```
Fx:id="mainAnchorPane"
```

Comment: Thanks @jonx. this was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the fxml to what @jonx suggested and everything works. below is the new FXML.

```
 <AnchorPane  fx:id="mainAnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
```